# incompatibilidade react-native 0.55.4

Tags: firebase, react, react-native

```
react-native init --version 0.55.4 aplicativo
```

Usei a versão 0.55.4 porque a versão atual esta dando o erro  500

```
npm install firebase --save
```

Utilizei esses dois comandos no console, e fui pro projeto colocar a referencia do firebase

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
```

Quando dou **react-native run-android**, aparece o erro 500

Erro no **node:**

> error: unable to resolve module 'firebase' from app.js module firebase

Comment: Tente iniciar o servidor com `npm start` e depois execute o `react-native run-android`

Comment: Não funcionou =/

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria utilizar a lib [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) para realizar esta integração e é compatível com versões superiores à 0.55 conforme documentação.

Answer (score 0):

Be happy

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database';
```